# Ruby on Rails The action could not be found for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails app says:

```
The action 'myjson' could not be found for UsersController
```

I've read all day other posts and it seems it's mostly caused by a missing end or something else. But I really don't think it's this because I've really tried to look it up and found nothing. So I'm turning to you for some help. Here's my controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction  #method in helpers to sort
 before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy] 
 before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
 before_filter :admin_user,     only: [:destroy]

 def index
  @user = current_user
  @usersall = User.all
  @users =User.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  @rank = User.select("users.name, sum(credits.score) AS rank").joins(:credits).group("credits.user_id").all
end

 def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  redirect_to users_path
 end

 def create

   if User.exists?(:email => params[:user][:email])
    flash.now[:error] = "A user with this email already exists"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
   elsif params[:user][:password] != params[:user][:password_confirmation]
    flash.now[:error] = "The passwords do not match. Try again"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
   elsif params[:user][:email] !~ /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
   elsif params[:user][:name] == nil
    flash.now[:error] = "The name field cannot be empty"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
   elsif params[:user][:password].length < 6
    flash.now[:error] = "Password is too short (minimal length: 6)"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
   else
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save
    redirect_to @user
   end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render :layout => 'user-layout.html.erb' #use a special layout
end

def edit
  render :layout => 'user-layout.html.erb' #use a special layout
end

def update
  if User.exists?(:email => params[:user][:email]) && params[:user][:email] != @user.email
    flash.now[:error] = "A user with this email already exists"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
  elsif params[:user][:new_password] != params[:user][:password_confirmation]
    flash.now[:error] = "The passwords do not match. Try again"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
  elsif params[:user][:email] !~ /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
  elsif params[:user][:name] == nil
    flash.now[:error] = "The name field cannot be empty"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
  elsif !@user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
    flash.now[:error] = "Entered password doesn't match with the one previously saved"
    render :action => :new, :layout => 'signin-layout.html.erb'
  else

    @user.update_attribute(:name, params[:user][:name])
    @user.update_attribute(:email, params[:user][:email])

    if params[:user][:new_password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation] && params[:user][:new_password].length > 6
    @user.update_attribute(:password, params[:user][:new_password])
  end

  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user
 end
end


def upAdmin
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attribute(:admin,true)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated, welcome to the new admin"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:error] = "Profile can't be upgraded to admin !'"
    redirect_to @user
  end
end

def downAdmin
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attribute(:admin,false)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated, bye to the old admin"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:error] = "Profile can't be updated !'"
    redirect_to @user
  end
end

def myteam
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.team_id != nil
    @team = Team.find @user.team_id
  end
  render layout: 'user-layout.html.erb'
end

def myjson
  render :layout => 'myjson.html.erb'
end

def myprojects
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render layout: 'user-layout.html.erb'
end

def mydevices
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render layout: 'user-layout.html.erb'
end

def mypins
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render layout: 'user-layout.html.erb'
end

private

def sort_column
  User.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end

def signed_in_user
  redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_path) unless (current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?)
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end

end
```

So I hope I just missed it and it's nothing serious. Just in case this is my routes.rb for the users :

```
get "users/new"

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'myteam'
      get 'myprojects'
      get 'mydevices'
      get 'mypins'
      get 'upAdmin'
      get 'downAdmin'
      get 'myjson'
    end
  end
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: It looks like you have too many `end` keywords (look at `update` method) Don't you have `SyntaxError` with this code?

Comment: marek: Everything except for the myjson method works fin, there's no exception or error, and at update method there's one end for the if, one for else, and one for the method.

Comment: Where is the extra `end`. I don't see it anywhere. In fact, I beautified the code in ST3, it looks fine.

Comment: @DenisDavydov Can you share the complete server log generated when you get this error.

Comment: When I edit your question it looks like there are a couple of characters at the start of the line immediately preceding `def myjson`.  Since you are pasting the code into a textarea on this site they are just showing up as whitespace - but check your file carefully, you might have some control character which is causing the `def` statement to be missed.